# CollectionviewCell cell layer will not trigger didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a 3x3 collectionview with 9 cells and I create a animation function to move cell layer to random point in the view.
 I'm trying to detect tap gesture when user tap on specific cell, but didSelectItemAt and touchesBegan will not trigger. Is there any way to detect which cell is tapped? or shouldn't I move cell layer with path?
Code above is my animation function

```
var toX: CGFloat = 0.0
var toY: CGFloat = 0.0
let inset = (self.view.frame.width - collectionView.frame.width) / 2
let backView = collectionView
toX = CGFloat.random(in: inset...inset + collectionView.frame.width - view.frame.width)
toY = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...collectionView.frame.height - view.frame.height)
let randomTo = CGPoint(x: toX, y: toY)
let control1 = randomControlPoint(x1: start, x2: randomTo)
let control2 = randomControlPoint(x1: start, x2: randomTo)
let path = createCurvePath(start: start, to: randomTo, control1: CGPoint(x: control1.x, y: control1.y), control2: CGPoint(x: control2.x, y: control2.y))
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

let moveAlongPath = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
let curvePath = path
moveAlongPath.path = curvePath.cgPath
moveAlongPath.duration = 3
moveAlongPath.calculationMode = CAAnimationCalculationMode.paced
moveAlongPath.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)]

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
    self.randomPointAnimation(start: randomTo, view: view, collectionView: backView)
})
let layer = createLayer(view: view)
layer.add(moveAlongPath, forKey: "animate along Path")
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: didSelectItemAt is UICollectionView delegate method. Have you set up the delegate correctly?

Comment: Yes. didSelectItemAt will still trigger but not on the layer I tapped. It seems to stick on the cell. Is it possible to use tap on layers in collectionview?